# How to move image in div with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an image located inside a div, I am trying to move it 50 px down and 50 px left in order to have everything complete. But I am not sure how to edit the image in the CSS since I don't know what code to put in to connect the photo to the css.

My code:

```css
#OverviewText4 img:MoneyIcon.png {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="OverviewText4">
  <img src="MoneyIcon.png" />
</div>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in CSS as per the multitude of answers. If I might suggest, since the image name in your example is related to iconography a slightly different approach:

```
#OverviewText4 {
    position: relative;
}
#OverviewText4:before {
  content: "";
  background: transparent url(MoneyIcon.png) scroll no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zk8su1qw/

This way you don't even need an img tag in the HTML, which is desirable if its just presentational.

There is also an assumption in this answer that you want the image displayed over the top of any content in the `OverviewText4` div, rather than having content flow around the image. If this is not the case you would want to use margins and keep the image `position:` `static` or `relative`.

Answer (score 13):

Remove the image name from your declaration and make sure your container is set to `position: relative` so that your image is absolutely positioned against the right containing element in this instance `#OverviewText4`

```
#OverviewText4 {
    position: relative;
}

#OverviewText4 img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This is related to answer as whenever using position:absolute, good practise is use position:relative to parent..nice mate!!!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `position:relative` to parent `<div>` and then add `position: absolute;` to the `<img>`. Like this:

```css
#OverviewText4{
  position: relative;
}

#OverviewText4 img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="OverviewText4"> 
  <img src="MoneyIcon.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Right, your CSS is fine but your selector is not. I think this is what you were going for.

```css
#OverviewText4 img[src="MoneyIcon.png"] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="OverviewText4">
  <img src="MoneyIcon.png" />
</div>
```

I've changed `img:MoneyIcon.png` (which doesn't mean anything to CSS) to `img[src="MoneyIcon.png"]` which means an `img` tag where the `src` = MoneyIcon.png

The main problem here is if you change the src you have to change your CSS also, I'd recommend having a class like this:

```css
#OverviewText4 img.money-icon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="OverviewText4">
  <img class="money-icon" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: This is correct, but not advisable in case the image, or the file name/location ever needed to change. Worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

You can simpy do this with padding

```
#OverviewText4 img {
  padding:50px 0 0 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly all you have to do is add this style to your div where the image is located.

```
div > img {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: div is not a class so you can't write ".div>img" but "div>img"

Comment: @ElChupacabra sorry my bad... typo

Comment: it will work but only if there are no other divs with img inside on whole site :) using id/class is much better

Answer (score 1):

Use the `margin`attribute for creating a margin around an element. You can also use `padding` on the div element.

Try it like this:

```
#OverviewText4 img: MoneyIcon.png{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can link an image to a `CSS` class** by **adding the class name inside the tag** `<img>`

Working Example:

```css
body {
  background: #111
}
.OverviewText4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="MoneyIcon.png" class="OverviewText4" />
</body>
```